# Closed form solution for the diagonals of the symmetric matrix in RAM specification

Tags: matrix, path-model

**Question: Is there a closed-form solution to finding the residual variances of endogenous variables using RAM specification (for SEM and Path Analysis)?**

**Problem:** Suppose someone wants to represent the following path diagram in terms of a correlation matrix such that the estimated coefficients are *exactly* what the user specifies (in this case, a, b, c, etc).

[image: Path Diagram]

Under RAM specification, the asymmetric (A) and symmetric (S) matrices are as follows: 
$$\begin{align}A & = 
\begin{pmatrix}
&     Z & G & S & T & P & X & Y \\ 
Z   & 0 & c & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
G   & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
S   & a & b & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 
T   & d & f & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
P   & e & g & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
X   & 0 & 0 & 0 & h & 0 & 0 & 0\\
Y   & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & i & 0 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
$$

$$\begin{align}S & = 
\begin{pmatrix}
&     Z & G & S & T & P & X & Y \\ 
Z   & \epsilon_1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
G   & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
S   & 0 & 0 & \epsilon_2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 
T   & 0 & 0 & 0 & \epsilon_3 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
P   & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \epsilon_4 & 0 & 0\\
X   & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \epsilon_5 & 0\\
Y   & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \epsilon_6\\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
$$

The expected covariance matrix ($C$) is then $(I-A)^{-1}S(I-A)^{-1\prime}$. If I pick the right values for $\epsilon_1-\epsilon_6$, the diagonals of $C$ will be exactly one (and the corresponding weights for a-i will be exactly the same as those specified in the diagram).

The problem is that I have no idea what to set the weights of $e_1-e_6$ to.

In the past, I've solved the problem by doing an optimization algorithm in R. This works quite well, but it takes a while when I'm doing a simulation with 10K iterations. I would think there's a closed-form solution to the problem. In other words:

$$\begin{align}
diag(C) &= diag[(I-A)^{-1}S(I-A)^{-1\prime}] \\
&= [1,1,1,...]
\end{align}$$

Note that I want to have a general solution to the problem, not just a solution for this particular model.

**What I've tried**
I've tried to get rid of the inverse (because that's where the problem becomes most tricky) using a theorem (can't remember the name) that states that the inverse of a matrix can be expressed as a geometric series ($(I-A)^{-1} = \sum_{0}^{\infty}A^{r}$), and that series terminates when A is nilpotent at $r$, but I can't figure out a general way of determining at what point that nilpotency takes place (it differs from one model to the next).

Any ideas?